# How to calculate a deformation gradient in Python. (On a cube in 3D)

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-algebra

I am trying to calculate [Large(Langrangian/Green) Strains](http://www.continuummechanics.org/greenstrain.html) in python on a cube I have artificially deformed. I am having trouble calculating the deformation matix, **F**:

[image]

#### Non-deformed Cube:

[image: non deformed cube]

#### Deformed Cube:

[image: deformed cube]

Cube coordinates are x1 and x2

```
x1 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0, 1.0],[0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
x2 = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.5, 0.0, 1.5],[0.0, 1.5, 1.5], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]]
global_coords[0] = x1
global_coords[1] = x2

def positions_at_t(global_coords, t):
    gc = np.array(global_coords)
    new_coords = gc[0] + t*(gc[1] - gc[0])
    return list(new_coords)
```

`gc[1]-g[2]` works as a gradient over time as we can see above. But the problem is it is defined in a 8x3 matrix as we would expect a 3x3 for a deformation gradient.

#### Side note/question:

On this site he generates equations that define the movement of points in (x,y,z) to then differentiate with respect to (X,Y,Z) to get F. Is there a library I can use to get these equations? (or the gradients?)

Comment: @Rob I appreciate that you are trying to keep the site on topic, yet I have read the rules and if this question doesn't fit into a 'a specific programming problem' or 'software algorithm' I would like to hear your reason why.

I do ask for a library, but i _specifically_ put it in an area titled 'side note'. Why should we reinvent the wheel if someone has already designed software for this specific type of problem? 

I know you are trying to help but what about users of this site that want to implement green strains using a python algorithm? This will be a useful resource for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Deformation Gradient, F

The deformation gradient is described as:

[image: Deformation Matrix]

So solving for F will be:

F = dX\dx

Where '\' is left matrix division, roughly equivalent to inv(A) * B.

This is a linear algebra problem with 9 variables and 9 equations.

### Green Strain, E

From http://www.continuummechanics.org/greenstrain.html:

[image: Green strain equations]

Implementing this in python using numpy looks like:

```
dx = x1
dX = x2
F = np.linalg.solve(dX[5:],dx[5:])
C = F.T @ F
E = .5*(C-np.identity(3))
E
(output:)array([[ 1.5  ,  0.125, -0.125],
       [ 0.125,  1.5  , -0.125],
       [-0.125, -0.125,  0.   ]])
```

Comment: `np.matrix.transpose(F)*F` -> `F.T @ F`

Comment: OOoo nice. I didn't know about either of those operands. Should I adjust the awnser?

Comment: Sure. np.matrix is obsolete and deprecated nowadays.